# Supplementing the missing value based on the declared number of consecutive values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df which is usually missing the first value. I want to complete it, because NA prevents some analyzes.

```
read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1    odczyt.2    diff.1
2023-07-26 14:30:01 NA  256.834 NA
2023-07-26 15:00:00 256.834 256.935 0.101
2023-07-26 15:30:00 256.935 257.122 0.187
2023-07-26 16:00:00 257.122 257.245 0.123
2023-07-26 16:30:00 257.245 257.649 0.404
2023-07-26 17:00:00 257.649 257.764 0.115
2023-07-26 17:30:00 257.764 257.942 0.178
2023-07-26 18:00:00 257.942 258.047 0.105", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) -> df1
```

Result should be

```
read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1    odczyt.2    diff.1
2023-07-26 14:30:01 256.697 256.834 0.137
2023-07-26 15:00:00 256.834 256.935 0.101
2023-07-26 15:30:00 256.935 257.122 0.187
2023-07-26 16:00:00 257.122 257.245 0.123
2023-07-26 16:30:00 257.245 257.649 0.404
2023-07-26 17:00:00 257.649 257.764 0.115
2023-07-26 17:30:00 257.764 257.942 0.178
2023-07-26 18:00:00 257.942 258.047 0.105", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) -> df1
```

The value 0.137 is the average of three consecutive values (0.101, 0.187, 0.123) and the value 256.697 = 256.834 - 0.137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution is to use `zoo::rollmean` and `dplyr::lead`. Here, we define the number of rows to average as `n`

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1    odczyt.2    diff.1
'2023-07-26 14:30:01' NA  256.834 NA
'2023-07-26 15:00:00' 256.834 256.935 0.101
'2023-07-26 15:30:00' 256.935 257.122 0.187
'2023-07-26 16:00:00' 257.122 257.245 0.123
'2023-07-26 16:30:00' 257.245 257.649 0.404
'2023-07-26 17:00:00' 257.649 257.764 0.115
'2023-07-26 17:30:00' 257.764 257.942 0.178
'2023-07-26 18:00:00' 257.942 258.047 0.105", header = TRUE)

n <- 3

df1$diff.1 <- ifelse(!is.na(df1$diff.1), df1$diff.1,
  dplyr::lead(zoo::rollmean(df1$diff.1, n, na.pad = TRUE), n - 1))

df1$odczyt.1 <- df1$odczyt.2 - df1$diff.1

df1
#>                    DT odczyt.1 odczyt.2 diff.1
#> 1 2023-07-26 14:30:01  256.697  256.834  0.137
#> 2 2023-07-26 15:00:00  256.834  256.935  0.101
#> 3 2023-07-26 15:30:00  256.935  257.122  0.187
#> 4 2023-07-26 16:00:00  257.122  257.245  0.123
#> 5 2023-07-26 16:30:00  257.245  257.649  0.404
#> 6 2023-07-26 17:00:00  257.649  257.764  0.115
#> 7 2023-07-26 17:30:00  257.764  257.942  0.178
#> 8 2023-07-26 18:00:00  257.942  258.047  0.105
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
df1$diff.1[is.na(df1$diff.1)] <- mean(df1$diff.1[2:(2+(n-1))])
df1$odczyt.1[is.na(df1$odczyt.1)] <- lead(df1$odczyt.1) - df1$diff.1
```

Was this what you had in mind?

If not, it might be easier for you to create a slightly longer example, with a few different test cases to show what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your tip and interest in my question. In the given example, the average is calculated from three values. In other cases it is reasonable to take an average of 5 values, and in still others 24.

Comment: how do you decide which is which? @GrBa

Comment: n<- 3  and  mean(df1$diff.1[2:(2+(n-1))])